# set values of class in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I'm trying to set the values of a class in a user control from another pages code behind and cant get it to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class itemtest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public DataRowView DataRowItem { get; set; }

public class Headers 
{
    public string strItems { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Headers hdrs = new Headers();
    string strItems = hdrs.strItems;

    if (strItems != null)
    {
        List<string> lstHeaders = strItems.Split(',').ToList<string>();
        DataTable dtHeaders = new DataTable();
        dtHeaders.Columns.Add("Header", typeof(String));
        dtHeaders.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(String));
        foreach (var item in lstHeaders)
        {
            DataRow drHeaders = dtHeaders.NewRow();
            drHeaders["Header"] = item.ToString();
            drHeaders["Value"] = DataRowItem[item.ToString()].ToString();
            dtHeaders.Rows.Add(drHeaders);
        }
        rptHeaders.DataSource = dtHeaders;
        rptHeaders.DataBind();
    }
}

}
```

and in my other page.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ListViewTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string strTableHeaders;
public DataRowView DataRowItem { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strTableHeaders = "UserID,MachineName";
}

protected void lvExample_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        itemtest itemHeaders = (itemtest)e.Item.FindControl("itemsMain");
        if (itemHeaders != null)

            itemHeaders.Headers.strItems = strTableHeaders;


    }
}
}
```

i get the error
Compiler Error Message: CS0572: 'Headers': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'itemtest.Headers' instead
for line
itemHeaders.Headers.strItems = strTableHeaders;

anyone help me out? im quite new to this, so lamen terms would be best

Thanks

EDIT:
my old method was just

```
public DataRowView DataRowItem { get; set; }
public string strItems { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (strItems != null)
    {
        List<string> lstHeaders = strItems.Split(',').ToList<string>();...
```

But what seems to be happening is my usercontrol page load event is triggering before the listview_itemdatabound event, which i dont see how thats possible since the usercontrol is only used in the listview...

So strItems is always null and my page load fails

Comment: Why would you want to set values in a usercontrol from a class - sounds like you are not using the userControl correctly? However, have you thought of using the contructor to pass the data across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These line:

```
public class Headers 
{
    public string strItems { get; set; }
}
```

**just declares** new type. They do not instantiate it. But this line:

```
itemHeaders.Headers.strItems = strTableHeaders;
```

tries to do the following: in `itemHeaders` get member `Headers` (which is actually just declaration of some new type which CAN be instantiated [created]) and set its member `strItem` to `strTableHeaders`.

The solution is easy. Add this line to your class `itemtest`

```
public Headers Hdrs { get; set; }
```

Which will instantiate `Headers` class as member property named `Hdrs`.

PS: Also please rethink the concept. As Hexie says, this is not correct way. I just solved your issue with comment.

Comment: Will this even compile? Since the `Headers` class belongs to the UserControl namespace, won't the `Headers` property cause a conflict?

Comment: Well my code still isnt working using this way my usercontrol page load event is loading before my listview itemdataboundevent for some reason

Comment: My guess is the `PageLoad` is always trigerred as one of the first events. Definitely it is trigerred before `ItemDataBound` event. You may (for simplicity) take `PageLoad` as the initializer for your component.

Comment: I have another page that it works on though, with almost the same code :|

Do you know how i can get this to work

Comment: It's hard to advice here. Try to read and understand this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx. Also ask something more specific (in new question). Get IT to work is very complex as noone knows what is IT :-)

Comment: I think the error you describe now (with the events) is different one from the original one (the compilation problem), isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This line below is incorrect:

```
itemHeaders.Headers.strItems = strTableHeaders;
```

What it's attempting to do is reassign what the `Headers.strItems` means. This is obviously not what you meant to do. What you need is a public reference to an actual instance of a Headers class object, not the definition of the class itself. In your UserControl you need

```
private Headers _hdrs;
public Headers Hdrs 
{
    get
    {
        return _hdrs ?? (_hdrs = new Headers());
    }
}
public DataRowView DataRowItem { get; set; }
```

Then in your page you can use:

```
itemHeaders.Hdrs.strItems = strTableHeaders;
```

This will actually assign the value at the instance.